# Is there any technical reason to typedef void?

Tags: c, typedef

No opinions, please. Is there any technical reason to typedef void?

My current company and my last both have `typedef void XYZ_void;` where `XYZ` is the project name.

I can understand a typedef for `XYZ_INT`, but void?

Is someone afraid that the size of void might be different on another architecture?!

Comment: Voting to migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't see any technical reason; I do have opinions against doing that.

Comment: Notice also that you don't want to (and you should avoid) use `sizeof(void)` or `sizeof(XYZ_void)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1666224/841108

Comment: I first assumed the statement about `sizeof(void)` being an intended joke. To my surprise I learned that there seem to be some people out there who actually try this.

Comment: Not relaed, but intersting I once had a C++ interview when I was asked how much memory the compiler would allocate if I declared atotally empty class - no functions, no data.

Comment: @Mawg, hopefully, you gave the only valid answer to that question: "who cares?" ;)

Comment: It riles me, as it does Basil. It smacks of cargo cult coding, where those doing it do not really understand what or why they are doing. To me, it's a code smell. I can't find anyone responsible, to ask them to justify it, so thought that I would ask here.

Comment: @David it was an "I'm smarter than you are and know more obscure trivia" kind of interview, but the question had appoint. You were supposed to realize that it is still possible to instantiate an object of the empty class, which means that you could have a pointer to it, so it had to have a memory address, so the compiler had to allocate one byte to it. Next item I want to test a program in a low memory situation, I will just sit in a tight loop, instantiating objects of the empty class ;-)

Comment: 6.2.5/19: "The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that
cannot be completed.".  `void` has no size; it has no values; and there is absolutely no *technical* reason why you would ever need to create a `typedef` for it.  Abstraction reasons, organizational reasons, maintenence reasons, sure.  But no *techincal* reasons.

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer

Comment: I just ran into a reason to use a typedef for void. I have a macro which takes a type parameter, specifying the type of a context structure. This becomes a typedef that is related to another parameter by name. Under the hood, there will be a pointer to that type.   There is a flavor of the macro which doesn't have the context parameter. It calls the full macfro, passing it `void` as the type; and that ends up being typedefed, so the context will be the default `void *` if it is still used.

Comment: ^ The point is that avoiding the `typedef` of the `void` default would require the two flavors of the macro to be separately implemented, with much identical content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment.

Here's the language from the [online C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.2.5 Types**
> ...
> 19     The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that
> cannot be completed.
> ...
> **6.3.2.2 void**
> 1     The (nonexistent) value of a *void expression* (an expression that has type `void`) shall not
> be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to `void`) shall not be
> applied to such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void
> expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its
> side effects.)
> ...
> **6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**
> ...
> 1     The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an
> incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that
> designates a bit-field member. The `_Alignof` operator shall not be applied to a
> function type or an incomplete type.

So, basically, `void` implies *no* value, and has *no* size (which is not the same as size `0`).  You cannot have any *objects* of type `void`.  Thus, platform doesn't play a role here at all.

Now, `void *` may be a different issue - the size and representation of a `void *` *may* vary between implementations, and in the past I've `typedef`d `void *` for abstraction purposes.

Note that dereferencing a `void *` leaves you with a `void` expression, which as stated above has no value and no size; that's why you can't do pointer arithmetic on a `void *`, and why you need to convert it to a different pointer type before attempting to dereference it.

Now that I think about it, there *is* one technical reason why you would need to create a `void` typedef - if you need to support both an ancient<sup>1</sup> K&R implementation and a post-C89 implementation.  The `void` data type wasn't introduced until the 1989 standard; before then, you'd type a function to return `int` (or rely on implicit typing) and ignore the return value:

```
foo()  /* implicit int type */
{
  /* do something interesting */
  return 0;
}

bar() /* implicit int type */
{
  ...
  foo(); /* return value is ignored */
  return 0;
}
```

So, let's say you want to support that code on both K&R and ANSI platforms, and you want to be good and use the `void` keyword where it's available, so your ANSI code reads as

```
void foo( void ) /* takes no parameters, returns no values */
{
  /* do something interesting */
}

void bar( void )
{
  ...
  foo();
  ...
}
```

Except this code won't compile on the K&R implementation, since it doesn't recognize the `void` keyword.  Even worse, `void` has multiple meanings in the code above; it indicates the the function doesn't return a value, *and* that it takes no parameters.  We can't just do `typedef int void`, because that would break the function parameter declaration.  We also need the `return 0` in the K&R code, since an `int` function *must* return an `int` value.

So, we'd need to do something like this:

```
#if !defined( __STDC__ ) || !defined( __STDC_VERSION__) /* Assume K&R implementation */
  typedef int XYZ_void;
  #define void 
  #define XYZ_void_return return 0
#else
  typedef void XYZ_void;
  #define XYZ_void_return
#endif

                               /* K&R equivalent      ANSI equivalent  */
XYZ_void foo( void )           /* int foo( )          void foo( void ) */
{                              /* {                   {                */
  ...                          /*   ...                 ...            */
  XYZ_void_return;             /*   return 0;                          */
}                              /* }                   }                */
                               /*                                      */
XYZ_void bar( void )           /* int bar( )          void bar( void ) */
{                              /* {                   {                */
  ...                          /*   ...                 ...            */
  foo();                       /*   foo();              foo();         */
  XYZ_void_return;             /*   return 0;                          */
}                              /* }                   }                */
```

I've shown how the code is processed for both K&R and ANSI implementations.  Again, this is the *only* use case I can think of for creating a typedef for `void`.

---

1. At least 27 years old.

Comment: "an incomplete object type that cannot be completed"?  What in the world does that mean?!?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: For example, `struct foo;` declares an incomplete structure type. Given that declaration, the compiler only knows that it's a structure, not what it contains. You can declare pointers to it and not much else. Later in the code, you can provide the full definition: `struct foo { int data; struct foo *next; };`. Now the incomplete type has been completed; you can now, for example, define objects of type `struct foo`. `void` is an incomplete type (you can't define an object of type `void`) that cannot be completed.

Comment: There is still no point in defining XYZ_void. In that old compiler, void is not a reserved word, so just typedef int void.

Comment: @gnasher729: that'll break the parameter list declarations.